# Is it possible to keep reference link between list and numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I create a list in python, and assign a different list to it, changes of the first list are reflected in the second list:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
a[0] = 0
print(b)
>>> [0, 2, 3]
```

Is it possible to achieve this behavior when creating a numpy array from a list?
What I want:

```
import numpy as np
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = np.array(a)
a[0] = 0
print(b)
>>> [ 0 2 3 ]
```

But what actually happens is that b is `[ 1 2 3 ]`. I realize that this is difficult due to dynamic resizing of the list. But if I could tell numpy that this list is never resized, it should work somehow.
Is this behavior achievable? Or am I missing some really bad drawbacks?

Comment: "If I create a list in python, and assign a different list to it, changes of the first list are reflected in the second list" - no, you don't have a first list and a second list. You have **one list** and two names for it. With `np.array(a)`, you're making an actual second object. You can't have it mirror changes to the list it was created from; NumPy arrays don't support that and couldn't support it without sacrificing almost everything that justifies their existence.

Comment: Yes, I was aware that it is just a different name. Thanks, I thought that it wouldn't work, but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally the issue is that Python lists *are not really arrays*. OK, CPython lists are ArrayLists, but they are arrays of Py_Object pointers, so they can hold heterogenous data. See [here](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/) for an excellent exposition on the implementation details of CPython lists. Also, they are resizable, and all the `malloc` and `realloc` gets taken care of under the hood. However, you *can* achieve something like what you want if you use vanilla Python arrays available in the [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) module.

```
>>> import numpy as np # third party
>>> import array # standard library module
```

Let's make a *real* array:

```
>>> a = array.array('i', [1,2,3])
>>> a
array('i', [1, 2, 3])
```

We can use `numpy.frombuffer` if we want our `np.array` to share the underyling memory of the buffer:

```
>>> arr = np.frombuffer(a, dtype='int32')
>>> arr
array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
```

### EDIT: WARNING

As stated by @user2357112 in the comments:

> Watch out - `numpy.frombuffer` is still using the old buffer protocol
>   (or on Python 3, the compatibility functions that wrap the new buffer
>   protocol in an old-style interface), so it's not very memory-safe. If
>   you create a NumPy array from an `array.array` or `bytearray` with
>   `frombuffer`, you must not change the size of the underlying array.
>   Doing so risks arbitrary memory corruption and segfaults when you
>   access the NumPy array

Note, I had to explicitly pass `dtype='int32'` because I initialized my `array.array` with the `i` signed int typecode, which on my system corresponds to a 32 bit int. Now, presto:

```
>>> a
array('i', [1, 2, 3])
>>> a[0] = 88
>>> a
array('i', [88, 2, 3])
>>> arr
array([88,  2,  3], dtype=int32)
>>>
```

Now, if we use `dtype=object`, we actually can share the underlying objects. However, with numerical types, we *can't mutate*, only replace. However, we can wrap a Python `int` in a class to make a mutable object:

```
>>> class MutableInt:
...     def __init__(self, val):
...         self.val = val
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return repr(self.val)
...
>>> obj_list = [MutableInt(i) for i in range(1, 8)]
>>> obj_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Now, we create an array that consists of the same *objects*:

```
>>> obj_array = np.array(obj_list, dtype=object)
>>> obj_array
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=object)
```

Now, we can mutate the int wrapper in the list:

```
>>> obj_list[0].val = 88
>>> obj_list
[88, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

And the effects are visible in the `numpy` array!:

```
>>> obj_array
array([88, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=object)
```

Note, though, you've now essentially created a less useful version of a Python `list`, one that isn't resizable, and doesn't have the nice O(1) amortized `append` behavior. We also lose any memory efficiency gains that a `numpy` array might give you!

Also, note that in the above the `obj_list` and `obj_array` are not sharing the same underlying buffer, they are making *two different arrays of holding the same Py_Obj pointer values:

```
>>> obj_list[1] = {}
>>> obj_array
array([88, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=object)
>>> obj_list
[88, {}, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>>
```

We cannot access the underlying buffer to a python `list` because this is not exposed. Theoretically, they *could* if they exposed the buffer protocol: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#bufferobjects

But they don't. `bytes` and `bytearray` objects *do* expose the buffer protocol. `bytes` are essentially Python 2 `str`, and `bytearray` is a mutable version of `bytes`, so they are essentially mutable `char` arrays like in C:

```
>>> barr = bytearray([65, 66, 67, 68])
>>> barr
bytearray(b'ABCD')
```

Now, let's make a `numpy` array that shares the underlying buffer:

```
>>> byte_array = np.frombuffer(barr, dtype='int8')
>>> byte_array
array([65, 66, 67, 68], dtype=int8)
```

Now, we will see changes reflected across both objects:

```
>>> byte_array[1] = 98
>>> byte_array
array([65, 98, 67, 68], dtype=int8)
>>> barr
bytearray(b'AbCD')
```

Now, before you think you can use this to subvert the immutability of Python `bytes` objects, think again:

```
>>> bs = bytes([65, 66, 67, 68])
>>> bs
b'ABCD'
>>> byte_array = np.frombuffer(bs, dtype='int8')
>>> byte_array
array([65, 66, 67, 68], dtype=int8)
>>> bs
b'ABCD'
>>> byte_array[1] = 98
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
>>>
```

Comment: Watch out - `numpy.frombuffer` is still using the old buffer protocol (or on Python 3, the compatibility functions that wrap the new buffer protocol in an old-style interface), so it's not very memory-safe. If you create a NumPy array from an `array.array` or `bytearray` with `frombuffer`, you must not change the size of the underlying array. Doing so risks arbitrary memory corruption and segfaults when you access the NumPy array.

Comment: @user2357112 good advice. I would likely never actually use the above, but I simply wanted to illustrate a little bit about the `numpy` and `python` internals. I edited to add a warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

A list contains pointers to objects (in this case integers) elsewhere in memory.

```
b = a
```

`b` points to the same list as `a`.  It's just another name

```
c = a[:]
```

`c` is new, but it contains the same pointers as `a`

```
arr = np.array(a)
```

`arr` has the same numeric values as `a`, but it stores those values in its own databuffer.  It has, in effect, evaluated `a`, and made a new object.  There is no connection, other than by value, with `a`.

```
arr1 = arr[:]
```

a new array, but with a shared data buffer, a `view`.

```
arr2 = arr.copy()
```

a new array with its own data buffer.

```
arr[0]
```

is a number, created from `arr`.  It's equal in value to `a[0]` but does not reference the same numeric object.